# Spacemacs redefine main prefix `M-m`

Tags: spacemacs, prefix-keys

I am trying Spacemacs with emacs keybindings, so the commands starting with `SPC`, like `SPC f e d`, can be invoked by replacing `SPC` with `M-m`.

Since `M-m` is bound to `back-to-indentation` in stock emacs, I would like to remap the prefix `M-m` to `M-n`, so that I can then safely bind `M-m` to `back-to-indentation`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are settings for the leader key in your `.spacemacs` file.  I have remapped mine to Page Up, (which is represented as `<prior>` by emacs).  Here's what I have in my `.spacemacs`:

```
;; The leader key
dotspacemacs-leader-key "<prior>"
;; The key used for Emacs commands (M-x) (after pressing on the leader key).
;; (default "SPC")
dotspacemacs-emacs-command-key "<prior>"
;; The key used for Vim Ex commands (default ":")
dotspacemacs-ex-command-key ":"
;; The leader key accessible in `emacs state' and `insert state'
;; (default "M-m")
dotspacemacs-emacs-leader-key "<prior>"
```

You may not need to set all three here as I have, start with just the leader key accessible in emacs state ("M-m") and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm recovering the `back-to-indentation` functionality with `M-m M-m`. For now it seems to be a good compromise.

See my **dotspacemacs/user-config** configuration below:

```lisp
    (defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
      "Configuration for user code:
    This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
    configuration.
    Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
    before packages are loaded."
      (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
        "M-m" 'back-to-indentation))
```